# Ursina Engine Cube is not appearing under cube upon clicking

Tags: python, ursina

So i have my code and I want to appear a cube under a cube i will click. Then i want to check if there are cubes around this cube if in some place there isnt a cube then create one but i cant do this. Can someone help me?

```
from ursina import *
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController
app = Ursina(borderless = False)

player = FirstPersonController(model='none', position=(0,5,0), scale=2)


Sky()

overworld_ground = Entity(
    model = 'cube',
    scale = (32,2,18),
    position = (0,0,0),
    collider = 'mesh',
    color = color.rgb(0, 128, 0),
    texture = 'grass'
    )
class Voxel(Button):
    def __init__(self, position = (0,0,0)):
        super().__init__(
            parent = scene,
            position = self.position,
            model = 'cube',
            collider = 'box',
            rotation = (0,0,0),
            color = color.rgb(0, random.uniform(162,182), 0),
            scale = (2, 2, 2))
    def input(self, key):
        if self.hovered:
            if key == 'left mouse down':
                voxel = Voxel(self.position.y - 2)
                destroy(self)

for z in range(8):
        for x in range(8):
            voxel = Voxel(position = (x * 2 - 11,-1,z * 2 + 10))



app.run()
```

Comment: i get the same error as @CryptoFool.  For clarity this is the error message: `<built-in method getPos of Voxel object at 0x000002020BEFBDB0> returned NULL without setting an error`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems with your code.  When I fix both of these, I get something reasonable that I think will put you in a place where you can proceed with your development:

1. I get an error when I try to run your code, involving the line `position = self.position,`. This line makes no sense. Here, you reference the `position` attribute of the object that you're just starting to construct. Also, you aren't using the `position` parameter passed to the constructor.  To resolve both of these issues, I expect that what you want here is `position = position` to simply pass the passed in `position` along to the superclass's constructor.
2. This line looks suspicious as well: `voxel = Voxel(self.position.y - 2)`.  You're taking just the `y` component of an object's position and passing that to the `Voxel` constructor that expects a 3-d position.

I fixed both of these issues, and played around with where the new Voxels are created so that I could see them.  Once I did this, clicking on an existing Voxel caused a new one to appear and that one to disappear, which seems like what you want to see happening.

So here's my fixed version of your code that behaves more correctly:

```
from ursina import *
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController
app = Ursina(borderless = False)

player = FirstPersonController(model='none', position=(0,5,0), scale=2)


Sky()

overworld_ground = Entity(
    model = 'cube',
    scale = (32,2,18),
    position = (0,0,0),
    collider = 'mesh',
    color = color.rgb(0, 128, 0),
    texture = 'grass'
    )
class Voxel(Button):

    def __init__(self, position = (0,0,0)):
        super().__init__(
            parent = scene,
            position = position,  # <- was self.position
            model = 'cube',
            collider = 'box',
            rotation = (0,0,0),
            color = color.rgb(0, random.uniform(162,182), 0),
            scale = (2, 2, 2))

    def input(self, key):
        if self.hovered:
            if key == 'left mouse down':
                p = self.position
                p.z += 20
                voxel = Voxel(position=p)
                destroy(self)

for z in range(8):
        for x in range(8):
            voxel = Voxel(position = (x * 2 - 11,-1,z * 2 + 10))

app.run()
```